# spring boot maven how to build both war and jar file

Tags: maven, spring-boot, pom.xml

Hello I need to know how to build both war and jar file in one time by mavan install

I need to use war file for deploy on google app engine and jar file for execute on jenkin by command (java -jar ....)

this is pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.demo</groupId>
<artifactId>gae-demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-legacy</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>
        <artifactId>gae-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>${gae.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-labs</artifactId>
        <version>${gae.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
        <version>${gae.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
        <version>${gae.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies> 
<properties>
    <start-class>demo.Application</start-class>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>/</m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>
    <gae.version>1.8.8</gae.version>
    <gae.home>${settings.localRepository}/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/${gae.version}/appengine-java-sdk-${gae.version}</gae.home>
    <gae.application.version>test</gae.application.version>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
    ...
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy-file</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <packaging>jar</packaging>
                        <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                        <url>${project.distributionManagement.repository.url}</url>
                        <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                        <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</file>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        ...
```

this pom.xml can create war and jar file but if I try to execute jar file by this command java -jar ... 
it's show the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework/boot/SpringApplication
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that Spring Boot's Maven plugin isn't involved in the creation of the jar so it hasn't been made executable.

When Spring Boot repackages a war file it is made executable. This means that, rather than trying to build both a jar and a war, you can just run the war using `java -jar`.

Answer (score 5):

The answer by @andywilkenson is definitely my preferred method of doing this, but here's how to do it anyways:D

You will need to decide which deliverable is the 'main' artifact. I suggest using the jar, because it does not make sense to use a war file as a dependency (it doesn't really make sense to use a SpringBoot executable jar as a dependency either).

STEPS

1. Make the packaging value equal the packaging type of the main artifact ('jar').
2. Add the spring-boot-maven-plugin with standard configuration.
3. Add explicit declarations for the maven war and jar plugins.
4. Create execution configurations for each plugin, otherwise only the one matching the project packaging will run. The configuration only needs to be placed in the execution for that plugin.
5. Add a "classifier" to the secondary artifact. This is important so we know which is the main and which is a secondary artifact (like the 'sources' jar).

FINAL RESULT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <!--snip-->
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <!--snip-->
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <!--snip-->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>war</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>war</goal>
            </goals>
            <!--No Explicit phase needed-->
            <configuration>
              <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
              <classifier>war</classifier>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <!--
        Do not declare an execution for jar, since it is the main artifact.
        Doing so makes maven think you are trying to add another
        supplemental file.
        -->
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <!--snip-->
</project>
```

Done.